# Apache removes Authorization header

Tags: apache-2.2, reverse-proxy, http-basic-authentication

Apache is acting as a reverse proxy in my setup.
The application server running on port 8081 requires a valid `Authorization` header.
The header is set by the client application.
Apache seems to remove this header. It does not reach the server on port 8081.

```
<VirtualHost mydomain.com:443>
    ServerName mydomain.com
    ServerAlias www.mydomain.com

    <Proxy *>
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.pem

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPass / http://mydomain.com:8081/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://mydomain.com:8081/
</VirtualHost>
```

To verify the server on port 8081 is working correctly, I added `RequestHeader set Authorization "Basic XZY"` to that configuration. In this case, the header is processed correctly by the server on port 8081.

I also connected to the server on port 8081 directly from the client to make sure the client is really setting the correct header. That also worked well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out the the reason was a buggy client implementation.

Answer (score 2):

From the [mod_proxy_http docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy_http.html):

**proxy-chain-auth**:

If the proxy requires authentication, it will read and consume the proxy authentication credentials sent by the client. With proxy-chain-auth it will also forward the credentials to the next proxy in the chain. This may be necessary if you have a chain of proxies that share authentication information. *Security Warning: Do not set this unless you know you need it, as it forwards sensitive information!*

Is this what you are looking for?